# Android okhttp3 socket connection problem

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io, okhttp

Can't connect to socket server with error: `java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '404 Not Found'`.

Code:
`

```
private fun run() {
    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url(AppParams.SOCKET)
        .build()
    client.newWebSocket(request, this)
    client.dispatcher.executorService.shutdown()
}
```

`

Url format is: "https://url.com:3003/".

The SocketIO library works correctly

Tried to remove the prefix, change the port, use another link..

Answer (score 0):

You should change the link to "wss://url.com:3003/"